# Starting and ending functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing around with a short little code to see if I can get a function going while the user has their mouse down and then end it when they bring their mouse up. For this example I am trying to increment a number that I am displaying on the screen as the user moves their mouse while holding the button down. I want it to freeze and stop once they release the button, however the counter just resets and the count continues from 0 even though the button is not being pressed...

```
function dragInit(state, e) {
    var i = 0;
    $(document).on("mousemove", function() {
        if (state) {
            i+=1;
            $('#debug').text(i); //Show the value in a div
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on(
    {mousedown: function(e) {
        var state = true;
        dragInit(e, state);
    },
    mouseup: function(e) {
        var state = false;
        dragInit(e, state);
    }
    });
});
```

As an aside, is there a way I can display whether a variable is true or false onscreen? When I try it just says [object Object].

Comment: Aren't the e and state parameters in incorrect order in the declaration of dragInit()?

Comment: Oh man, you're right. This explains so much... Needed a fresh pair of eyes haha, thank you

Comment: You're adding *another* `mousemove` handler every time the mouse goes down or up. This'll add multiple handlers all doing the same thing. And your `state` variables being set in the other handlers are local variables not accessible to the `mousemove` handler. And you're not using `e` at all.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm still quite new at this, but I figured I could keep state in a local scope and just pass it to the function as I wrote above...

Comment: You're right. I misread the argument somehow. But you still don't need the local variable. Just pass `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function dragInit() {
    $(document).on("mousemove", function () {
        if (eventState.state) {
            eventState.count += 1;
            $('#debug').text(eventState.count); //Show the value in a div
        }
    });
}

// Create an object to track event variables
var eventState = {
    count:0, //replaces your previous 'i' variable
    state: false //keeps track of mouseup or mousedown
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on({
        mousedown: function (e) {
            eventState.state = true;
            dragInit(); //don't need to pass anything anymore
        },
        mouseup: function (e) {
            eventState.state = false;
            dragInit(); //don't need to pass anything anymore
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmADP/)

#### Or keep everything together as one object

```
var dragInit = function () {
    var count = 0;
    var state = false;
    var action = function () {
        $(document).on("mousemove", function () {
            if (state) {
                count += 1;
                $('#debug').text(count); //Show the value in a div
            }
        })
    };

    $(document).on({
        mousedown: function (e) {
            state = true;
            action(); //don't need to pass anything anymore
        },
        mouseup: function (e) {
            state = false;
            action(); //don't need to pass anything anymore
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = new dragInit();
});
```

[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mmADP/1/)

#### Example in response to comment

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpfwW/): This shows why the following code snippets differ in execution.

```
// Works
$(document).on("mousemove", function () {
    if (state) {

    }
})

// Doesn't
if (state) {
    $(document).on("mousemove", function () {

    });
}
```

Comment: I've been playing with your examples. In the second one, is there a reason why 
`$(document).on("mousemove", function () {
            if (state) {
                count += 1;
                $('#debug').text(count); //Show the value in a div
            }
        })` 
works, but
`if (state) {
        $(document).on("mousemove", function () {
                count += 1;
                $('#debug').text(count); //Show the value in a div
            })
        }`
does not?

Comment: @tomc Because there is no event calling `$(document).on()`. Wrapping it like you did, would execute at load time rather than an event call. Think of it this way. When you come home after a long day at work and call out "Is anybody home?" you expect either silence or someone to call back. Your shoutout is an event. You don't first sweep the house to see if anyone is home, go back, and then do your shoutout. Events must come first.

Comment: @tomc Check my example in the answer to explain further

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code. I suggest you to read more basic concepts before starting to use jQuery.

The order of the parameters passed to `dragInit()` is wrong on both `mouseup` and `mousedown` event bindings.

The reason your counter is restarting is because your variable `i` is local, so it exists only during the function context it is declared in.

You are making the same mistake with the state variable, but in this case it is completely unnecessary to declare it.

Consider making your counter a global (even though it is not a good practice).

I can't provide you code because I am answering from my phone. A solution would be create a `mousemove` event that checkes whether the mouse button is pressed before incrementing your counter.

Hope I helped

Comment: I didn't mean to focus on the counter resetting, which I actually intended in the above code. All excellent advice though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Less code, You just need this.

Use jquery on and [Off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to turn on and off mousemove event.

#### Counter Reset http://jsfiddle.net/kRtEk/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $(document).on({
        mousedown: function (e) {

            $(document).on("mousemove", function () {

                $('#debug').text(i++); //Show the value in a div
            });

        },
        mouseup: function (e) {
            i = 0;
            $('#debug').text(i);
            $(document).off("mousemove");
        }
    });
});
```

#### W/O Reset http://jsfiddle.net/gumwj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $(document).on({
        mousedown: function (e) {
             $(document).on("mousemove", function () {
                 $('#debug').text(i++); //Show the value in a div
            });

        },
        mouseup: function (e) {
            $(document).off("mousemove");
        }
    });
});
```

#### WithNoCounter http://jsfiddle.net/F3ESx/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on({
        mousedown: function (e) {
             $(document).on("mousemove", function () {
              $('#debug').data('idx',parseInt($('#debug').data('idx')|0)+1).text($('#debug').data('idx')); //Show the value in a div
            });

        },
        mouseup: function (e) {
            $(document).off("mousemove");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are married to Jquery (nothing wrong with that) - check out and consider entirely re-thinking your approach leveraging the ".one()"  (http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

edit: and if that taste doesn't sit well - familiarize yourself with the "deferred" object (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

lots of ways to approach this via jquery - what you decide in the end depends on what you really intend to do with this.

Comment: I'm trying to practice javascript and html5 canvas element by making a little program that displays a graph of progress on my daily life goals. The purpose of this specifically is to make a slider without using the jquery draggable function where I will drag the graph and once I reach the boundaries it will perform an ajax call to get additional data from prior days. That may be too much information, but a little context of where I'm going with it. So eventually I'd like to drop jquery and do it in pure javascript

Comment: @tomc - You've got it backwards.  Why would you want to "_eventually drop jQuery_"?  As others have suggested, you should learn JavaScript basics first, then learn jQuery (and other libraries), then never look back.  Why re-invent the wheel _after_ you've already driven a car around town a couple times?

Comment: I've used jQuery before and to me it seems like an easier solution than learning pure javascript. I understand the benefits, especially when it comes to cross-browser compatibility, but I really want to challenge myself to figure out how to do it without a framework

Comment: Gotcha.  That's probably the best/only reason I could think of to do it that way: for learning purposes.  I like it... Keep up the good work!